QGIS DataPlotly plugin colour settings
I have a layer with multiple ID. I would like to plot in different colours the different ID data in DataPlotly plugin. Is there a way to do this?

Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.
